# Can a Koa Application Use Another Koa Application?

Tags: node.js, middleware, koa

As the question suggests, I am having trouble using one `koa` application as middleware to another. With `express`, we can just do:

```
const express = require('express');
const expressApp = express();
const otherExpressApp = express();

app.use(otherExpressApp);
```

This same pattern works with `connect`. However, it is not working with `koa`:

```
const koa = require(`koa`);
const koaApp = koa();
const otherKoaApp = koa();

app.use(otherKoaApp);
```

gives me:

```
AssertionError: app.use() requires a generator function
    at Application.app.use (/home/sean/repos/koaka/node_modules/koa/lib/application.js:100:5)
    at repl:1:5
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:164:27)
    at bound (domain.js:250:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:263:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:392:12)
    at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:210:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:546:8)
```

`koa` gives a function that lets it be mounted as an `express`/`connect` application:

```
expressApp.use(koaApp.callback());
```

but this does not seem to work with `koa` itself:

```
koaApp.use(otherKoaApp.callback());
```

throws:

```
AssertionError: app.use() requires a generator function
    at Application.app.use (/home/sean/repos/koaka/node_modules/koa/lib/application.js:100:5)
    at repl:1:7
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:164:27)
    at bound (domain.js:250:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:263:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:392:12)
    at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:210:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:546:8)
```

**Can I use one `koa` application as middleware for another `koa` application?** If so, how? If not, is this behavior intended to be put in a future release? Why or why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to do this is to use `koa-mount`.

https://github.com/koajs/mount

```
var koa = require('koa');
var mount = require('koa-mount');
var app1 = koa();
var app2 = koa();
app1.use(mount(app2));
```

Alternatively mount it under a URL sub-path:

```
app1.use(mount('/api', app2));
```

koa differs from express by having a very minimal core. For example, express ships with a static webserver middleware, but koa does not. The fact that you need to import a separate module to do "X" in is simply how things are done in koa. Note however that `koa-mount` is still under the flagship koajs github repo, so it's more or less official.